# Escape rogue backslashes in a string

Tags: java, json, regex

I have a JSON string like this in the database:

```
{"name" : "DROCK", "details" : [{"age" : "23", "degree" : "BE", "Experience" : "worked in a company\6as an intern"}]}
```

I want to remove \ character but which is not a valid escape string. I tried using StringEscapeUtil but it is not helping me out here.

The code I've used here:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.xwork.StringEscapeUtils;

public class JSONEscape {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String testString = "{\"name\" : \"DROCK\", \"details\" : [{\"age\" : \"23\", \"degree\" : \"BE\", \"Experience\" : \"worked in a company\6as an intern\"}]}";
        System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(testString));
    }
}
```

How should I escape valid \ characters and remove rogue characters like this. but I would like to retain the valid escape characters like \n, \t,etc.

Finally i would like a result like this:

```
{"name" : "DROCK", "details" : [{"age" : "23", "degree" : "BE", "Experience" : "worked in a company6as an intern"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove bad escape sequences in a JSON string, then that's easy.

```java
String testString = "{\"name\" : \"DROCK\", \"details\" : [\"age\" : \"23\", \"degree\" : \"BE\", \"Experience\" : \"worked in a company\\6as an intern\"]}";
System.out.println(testString.replaceAll("\\([^bfnrt\"\\])", "$1"));
```

That RegEx literally just means "wherever a backslash is followed by an invalid escape character, drop the backslash".

Comment: Thanks @Leo Aso for your reply, I modified the replace string like this: 
    System.out.println(testString.replaceAll("\\\[^bfnrt\"\'\\\]", "$1"));

Now I can see ? in place of 6 in the SOP :(

Comment: Make sure that in your test string you type `\\6` not `\6`. If you are typing JSON directly in a string, you need to write the backslash twice, because Java recognizes `\6` as an escape sequence equal to `\u0006`, but if you type `\\6`, it will just leave it as `\6`.